# Clean nested lists in Python

Tags: python, list, data-cleaning

Say I have a list in Python:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, [a, [[9, 10, 11]], c, d], 5, [e, f, [6, 7, [8]]]]
```

I would like to clean all the nested lists so that, if they are of length 1 (just one item), the are "pulled up" out of the list, such that the revised list would look like:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, [a, [9, 10, 11], c, d], 5, [e, f, [6, 7, 8]]]
```

Naturally I can just check if `len == 1` and replace that index with its contents, but... Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: There is no built-in for this, no.

Comment: builtin way?  Nope.  The easiest solution is probably to just use a recursive function.

Comment: Assuming that you are already using recursion, it seems you should just keep doing the method you are doing.

Comment: There isn't even a builtin to flatten a list (anymore)!

Comment: Thanks; yes I was using recursion, but was wondering if there was a builtin option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function:

```
def expand_singles(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        if len(item) == 1:
            return expand_singles(item[0])
        return [expand_singles(i) for i in item]
    return item
```

Demo:

```
>>> def expand_singles(item):
...     if isinstance(item, list):
...         if len(item) == 1:
...             return expand_singles(item[0])
...         return [expand_singles(i) for i in item]
...     return item
... 
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, ['a', [[9, 10, 11]], 'c', 'd'], 5, ['e', 'f', [6, 7, [8]]]]
>>> expand_singles(l)
[1, 2, 3, ['a', [9, 10, 11], 'c', 'd'], 5, ['e', 'f', [6, 7, 8]]]
```

Comment: Fails for `x = []; x[:] = [x, 'hello']`

Comment: @wim: yes, this doesn't support self-referencing lists. I consider that out of scope in any case. You would have to add a memo to track list ids and ignore any already seen.